# Why does PySerial object give a no port error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am trying to create use a class where I call `recv` in `ConnectArduino`, however I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ConnectArduino' object has no attribute 'port'
```

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
class ConnectArduino:
    def __init___(self, port, baudrate):
        # if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        print('# Using port: ' + g_port + " and baudrate" + str(g_baudrate))
        self.port = serial.Serial(port=g_port, baudrate=g_baudrate)

    def open(self):
        self.port.open()

    def close(self):
        self.port.close()

    def send(self, msg):
        self.port.write(msg)

    def recv(self):
        return self.port.readline

def main():
    ConnectArduino().recv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try `__init__` instead of `__init___`

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to define a constructor with two arguments

```
def __init___(self, port, baudrate):
    # if len(sys.argv) == 3:'
    print('# Using port: ' + g_port + " and baudrate" + str(g_baudrate))
    self.port = serial.Serial(port=g_port, baudrate=g_baudrate)
```

So

```
ConnectArduino().recv()
```

should not work, except that there is an extra `_` in the `__init___` so things do not work as expected.

Comment: He also should fix the `g_port` and `g_baudrate` vars, the arguments are called `port` and `baudrate` after that change, it will work as spected